# Add 's' to string if number is 0 or greater than 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a web application in flask and I want to format the post votes better.

Instead of it saying "1 votes" I want it to say "1 vote" and so on.

My attempt:

```py
def format_post_votes(post):

    output = ''

    if post.votes == 0 or post.votes > 1:
        output = 's'
    else:
        output = ''

    return f'{post.votes}{output}'
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?..

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify it to:

```py
def format_post_votes(post):
    return f'{post.votes}{"" if post.votes == 1 else "s"}'
```